# recommended clothing for compromise betwee office and and biking home on a race bike?

Tags: clothes, commuter, racing-bikes

I recently started riding to work again. I'm using a hybrid (they're called that way. its a sporty bicycle with full gears and tires between city and mtb type tires) now, but i want to use my racing bike for it. however cycling in normal office clothes can get quite uncomfortable for the crotch because of the lower race position. I was wondering if there is a reasonable compromise possible. Like a company that makes clothes (specifically pants) for cycling commuters or something.

I cannot go full lycra because the facilites for changing clothes aren't there.

Comment: How far is your commute? I'd just go for the tight boxer short approach

Comment: There are a whole lot of [questions](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clothes) that address this issue, especially after the first page.

Comment: my commute is 21 km. I might try with cycling underpants under my normal pants.

Comment: also i did do a search and i did not find. but perhaps @andy256 could tell me which question i should have a look at then.

Comment: You don't have a bathroom stall at work?

Comment: Yeah we have a toilet sure. maybe i should change can't into won't. i'd find it embarrassing. much more practical to commute with my hybrid

Comment: If you are not going to shower once you get to work then you don't want to be wearing tight shorts under your pants all day long.

Comment: @Blam I don't mean cycling shorts but cycling underpants. they are like boxers with a small chamois.

Comment: @Blam yes you're right, no one needs to sit in a meeting next a guy with beaty swollocks.

Answer (score 2):

> ### "The facilities for changing clothes aren't there"

Yes they are, it's called a bathroom or a toilet stall, you don't have to have a locker room to swap a pair of pants, just wear your lycra for your ride and pack your clothes in your bag. Then change in the bathroom when you get to work.

Other than that, I once had a suit that was made out of **[wool-lycra](http://shop.nordstrom.com/sr?origin=keywordsearch&contextualcategoryid=0&keyword=lycra#keyword=lycra&type=keyword&currency=CAD&category=s6001656&defaultsize3=&size=&width=&color=&price=&brand=&stores=&instoreavailability=false&lastfilter=searchcategory_6001656&sizeFinderId=0&resultsmode=&segmentId=0&keywordSortEngine=RBS&page=1)**, they're a little more expensive, but the material was certainly stretchy.

Comment: I admit changing in the bathroom is theoretically possible, but it's not practical. but thanks for the tip on the material. Maybe I'll try it.